# Regex(sed): How to form replace pattern according to a variable?

Tags: regex, sed

I need to append a ".dev" or a ".prd" to a machine name depending on which domain they're in. The domain can be determined in the machine name, since they all follow the same pattern: hostd(..) for dev machines and hostp(..) for production machines.

Here's an example of what I want:

```
=============================
| input       | output      |
|=============|=============|
| hostd01     | hostd01.dev |
|-------------|-------------|
| hostp03     | hostp03.prd |
=============================
```

I'm new to sed, so I don't know how elegant is the solution I found (below).
Isn't there a way to do it in one line?

```
sed -e 's/\([dp]\)\(..\)/\1\2.\1/' 
    -e 's/d$/dev/' 
    -e 's/p$/prd/'
```

Comment: what is the actual input format?  Is it the table above?

Comment: No the actual input are the columns inside the table "hostd01" and "hostp03"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
$ sed '/d/{s/$/\.dev/} ; /p/{s/$/\.prv/}' input 
hostd01.dev
hostp03.prv
```